# Flutter provider throwing error setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, state-management, flutter-provider, flutter-state

I am trying to learn how to use the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package, version 4.0+. I have copy-pasted [solution](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/samples/master/provider_counter/lib/main.dart) provided by flutter team and run it on my emulator. The problem is, when I run it for the first time (cold start), I am getting the following error message:

[image: Error image]

When I refresh application (meaning, when I click the refresh arrow in VS Code that re-builds app), then it suddenly starts working. This means, that problem only occurs during first (cold) start.

I would really like to learn how to use this package; yet for unknown reason it throws this error. As I have read other articles, people were trying to modify value of a Class that implements ChangeNotifier during the build method; however in this scenario, this should not be the case.

Any help in respect to this matter would be highly appreciated.

P.S. here is the actual source code I was working with:

```
// Copyright 2019 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    // Provide the model to all widgets within the app. We're using
    // ChangeNotifierProvider because that's a simple way to rebuild
    // widgets when a model changes. We could also just use
    // Provider, but then we would have to listen to Counter ourselves.
    //
    // Read Provider's docs to learn about all the available providers.
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      // Initialize the model in the builder. That way, Provider
      // can own Counter's lifecycle, making sure to call `dispose`
      // when not needed anymore.
      create: (context) => Counter(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

/// Simplest possible model, with just one field.
///
/// [ChangeNotifier] is a class in `flutter:foundation`. [Counter] does
/// _not_ depend on Provider.
class Counter with ChangeNotifier {
  int value = 0;

  void increment() {
    value += 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
            // Consumer looks for an ancestor Provider widget
            // and retrieves its model (Counter, in this case).
            // Then it uses that model to build widgets, and will trigger
            // rebuilds if the model is updated.
            Consumer<Counter>(
              builder: (context, counter, child) => Text(
                '${counter.value}',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        // Provider.of is another way to access the model object held
        // by an ancestor Provider. By default, even this listens to
        // changes in the model, and rebuilds the whole encompassing widget
        // when notified.
        //
        // By using `listen: false` below, we are disabling that
        // behavior. We are only calling a function here, and so we don't care
        // about the current value. Without `listen: false`, we'd be rebuilding
        // the whole MyHomePage whenever Counter notifies listeners.
        onPressed: () =>
            Provider.of<Counter>(context, listen: false).increment(),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it's working fine here, what version of flutter are you using? run flutter doctor

Comment: I am using the beta channel build: v1.13.6

Comment: could you try using stable channel ?

Comment: done! :) answer sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine on `stable v1.12.13+hotfix.7` so probably it's a bug on the latest version.

My suggestion for you is to work on stable version and if you try dev or master and you find a bug, please report it here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues